# Quick Books integration using C#

Tags: quickbooks

I'm integrating Quick Books using C# with QODBC Provider,i encountered with an error when i added C# application to Task scheduler. and running Server Editions DCOM servers.

Error Message:

> . ERROR [00000] [QODBC] QB Begin Session Failed. Error = 80040408,
>   Could not start QuickBooks

Can i handle quick books with Scheduler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a well-known limitation of QuickBooks that the QuickBooks SDK (and all integrated applications, including QODBC) need a active GUI session to connect to QuickBooks.

Task scheduler and Windows services don't make a normal GUI session available, and so can't connect to QuickBooks.

If you search on [Intuit's developer forums](http://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com) you'll find tons of info/references to this.